# Odoo Ebay Connector

Tags: ebay-api, odoo-11, odoo-enterprise

I have installed ebay connector that is available with Odoo enterprise but when I tried to list product on ebay it throws error "At least one photo is required" I already have the image added to product. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the images as
attachment:

[image: Attachment]

Comment: Thanks I will try that and let you know